# How to cancel async task while uploading video using multipart in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm working on android application in which I'm uploading videos to server using multipart upload and `AsyncTask`.

I want to cancel `AsyncTask` after clicking on cancel button of progress bar 
here is my code.

```
uploadVideoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                                  uploadVideoButton.setEnabled(false);
                            uploadtoserver = new  UploadFileToServer();                                
                    uploadtoserver.execute(objVideoList.getImage_path());


}

private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddVideoActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Video...");
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     if (uploadtoserver != null && uploadtoserver.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
                          uploadtoserver.cancel(true);  
                }
            });

            progressDialog.show();

            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);
            // percentageTextView.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
            if(isCancelled())
            {
            return ;
            }
            else
            {
            progressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
            if(progress[0] == 100)
            {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Validating video from server...");
            //progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return uploadFile(params[0]);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        private String uploadFile(String filePath) {
            String responseString = null;

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);
            if(isCancelled())
            {
                publishProgress(CANCELLED);
            return(null);
            }
            try {
                AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                        new ProgressListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void transferred(long num) {


                                if(isCancelled())
                                {
                                publishProgress(CANCELLED);
                                return;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                publishProgress( (int) ((num * 100) / totalSize));
                                //int value = (int) ((num * 100) / totalSize);
                                }


                                //publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                            }
                        });

                File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

                // Adding file data to http body
                entity.addPart("video_file", new FileBody(sourceFile));

                String userId = new DevicePreferences().getString(
                        AddVideoActivity.this, Constants.PREF_USER_ID, "");
                entity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody(userId));
                entity.addPart("detail", new StringBody(descriptionEditText
                        .getText().toString()));
                entity.addPart("title", new StringBody(titletext.getText()
                        .toString()));
                entity.addPart("image_path", new StringBody(filePath));

                totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
                entity.addPart("video_size",
                        new StringBody(Long.toString(totalSize)));
                httppost.setEntity(entity);
                if(isCancelled())
                {
                    publishProgress(CANCELLED);
                return(null);
                }
                // Making server call
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    // Server response
                    responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
                } else {
                    responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                            + statusCode;
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                responseString = e.toString();
            }

            return responseString;

        }
         @Override
            protected void onCancelled(String result) {
             if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            new AlertMessage(AddVideoActivity.this)
                .showAToast("Cancelled by user");   
            uploadVideoButton.setEnabled(true);

            super.onCancelled(result);
            }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            //new AlertMessage(AddVideoActivity.this)
        //  .showAToast(result);
            if(!isCancelled())
            {
            Object json;
            try {
                json = new JSONTokener(result).nextValue();
                if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) json;
                    if (jsonObject.has("status")) {
                        if (jsonObject.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase(
                                "ok")) {
                            objVideoList
                                    .setVideo_id(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                            showAlert("Uploaded Successfully.",
                                    percentageTextView, progressBar, true);
                        } else {
                            showAlert("Some error occured", percentageTextView,
                                    progressBar, false);
                        }
                    } else {
                        showAlert(result, percentageTextView, progressBar,
                                false);
                    }
                } else {
                    showAlert(result, percentageTextView, progressBar, false);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                showAlert(result, percentageTextView, progressBar, false);
            } finally {
                uploadVideoButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
            }
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTasks are tricky to cancel. Better you use [OKHTTP](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) for example, so you cancel it [this way](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#canceling-a-call)

Answer (score -1):

to cancel asynctask uyou can call `uploadtoserver.cancel(true);`